# Faking all instances of every parent using Typemock

Tags: c#, typemock

I've recently started using Typemock and have looked through at least half a dozen existing threads, but can't seem to find an answer to my exact problem.

I have a class C that derives from B, that itself derives from A. The instance of C is what I need to test and therefore needs to be real. But as C derives from B (and indirectly A), I need those two classes completely faked automatically when I create an instance of C.

See below:

```
class A
{
    protected int methodA()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected int methodB()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public int methodC()
    {
        return methodA() * methodB();
    }
}

class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        A fake_A = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<A>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes, ConstructorWillBe.Ignored);
        Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(fake_A, "methodA").DoInstead((MethodCallContext ctx) =>
            {
                return 2;
            }
        );

        B fake_B = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<B>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes, ConstructorWillBe.Ignored);
        Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(fake_B, "methodB").DoInstead((MethodCallContext ctx) =>
            {
                return 10;
            }
        );

        C c = new C(); // Would expect A and B to be faked automatically since I've faked all instances above. 
        int method_c_val = c.methodC(); // I get back 5, but what I need returned is 20.
    }
}
```

This is an extremely simplified version of the problem I'm facing. It's not just a matter of faking behaviour of one or two methods in the parent classes. The entire parent heirarchy needs to be faked. So A and B both need to be faked completely, not partially.

One of the threads I've already looked at is this one, but the answer in there points to an address which is no longer available:

https://www.typemock.com/answers/11613/mocking-all-instances-of-a-base-class

Comment: Mocking parts of the application for system testing is argubly bad, mocking **aspects** of a **single object** sounds like a terrible idea.  If you really must do this I recommend you refactor to a _composition pattern_

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it's a terrible idea? Link to article, discussion, another thread, blog, something (anything) to back your statement? Not saying I don't believe you but some examples would go a long way...

Comment: Because your class isn't designed for this purpose.  all you have is a collection of methods with no _design pattern_.   Recommend the Design Patterns book by the "Gang of Four".  Wishing you well

Comment: I'm dealing with legacy code, and this limits my options.

Comment: Also, how may I ask did you deduce the fact that these classes don't use design patterns? I certainly don't see how you could've reached this conclusion based on the (hugely) simplified block of code I've posted. Because the fact is these classes do make use of design patterns. It's just that they weren't test driven and most things that aren't test driven are a b$%& to retrofit unit tests into.

Comment: I am commenting on what you've posted above **not** what I cannot see.  If your actual code differs to the point that it does not represent the above intention then any discussion to solve your dilemma would be irrelevant

Comment: Ok sorry, I probably should've stated that it's a simplified example.

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Answer (score 3):

As @Nkosi suggested you can use:

```
C c = Isolate.Fake.Instance<C>(Memebers.CallOriginal);
Isoalte.NonPublic.WhenCalled(c,"methodA").WillReturn(2);
Isoalte.NonPublic.WhenCalled(c,"methodB").WillReturn(10);
```

You fake the C object but it's methods still call the original implementation (If necessary), and you fake only the methods in question.

Comment: I've edited my question. Basically, it's not just a matter of faking behavior of couple methods...that was just an example to demonstrate that my approach I've already tried (with fakeAll) doesn't work. The actual situation I'm facing is rather complex and I need the whole of A and B faked, not just parts of it.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what are you trying to test. In this case, the methods inherited from the base classes are called by object C and not by A or B so faking them and their methods don't concern the C object.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with typemock, but if you are unable to get an answer, are in control of the code in question and able to modify it, I can suggest another possible workaround.

Make the methods in question `virtual`, giving the ability of derived classes to override them.

```
class A
{
    protected virtual int methodA()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected virtual int methodB()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public int methodC()
    {
        return methodA() * methodB();
    }
}
```

To test `methodC` in isolation you can create a stub class D derived from C that overrides the methods in question.

```
class D : C
{
    protected override int methodA()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    protected override int methodB()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

With that the test would perform just as expected.

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodC()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expected = 20;
        var c = new D();

        //Act
        int actual = c.methodC();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

I would think that with typemock you would need to do something similar by faking `C` and only isolating the two dependency methods in question, leaving the method under test to be called naturally. But again I am not that familiar with that framework.

Comment: Yes, this would work in the environment you've mentioned at the start, but even then it's a lot of code to create (what is essentially) a workaround. And this is just a very simplified example. Even if I could edit code for A and B (which I can't), the actual classes for A and B are monstrosities. To do a true isolation test, I'd have to ovverride a lot more methods in each class. This is where Typemock comes in. It lets me fake all methods (recursively) down to their default primitive values, and I can just have my mock exhibit custom behaviour in specific places, such as methods.